# Move functionality out of class

Tags: c#, .net-core, func

I want to have the timeout logic `.TimeoutAfter(...)` out of this web socket wrapper class, so it's customizable. I won't paste the whole class because it's not needed, but it can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tekr/DeribitDotNet/blob/b5770ff79b4cafa7df99f200846c4fb4bf87c47b/DeribitDotNet/Utils/ResilientWebSocket.cs#L172).

```cs
await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_url, CancellationToken.None).TimeoutAfter(OpenTimeoutMs).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, int timeoutMs)
    {
        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeoutMs)) != task)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException($"Operation timed out after {timeoutMs} ms");
        }
    }
}
```

### My thoughts

Is the best to use `Func<something>`?

```cs
public Func<Task> DoTimeout { get; set; }

await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_url, CancellationToken.None).DoTimeout().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

### The web socket wrapper

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

namespace DeribitDotNet.Utils
{
    public class ResilientWebSocket : IDisposable
    {
        private const int CloseTimeoutMs = 5000;
        private const int OpenTimeoutMs = 5000;
        private const int SendTimeoutMs = 5000;

        private const int RetryOpenDelayMs = 5000;

        private readonly AsyncManualResetEvent _connectionWaitHandle = new AsyncManualResetEvent();

        private ClientWebSocket _webSocket;
        private int _reconnecting;
        private bool _disposed;

        private readonly Uri _url;

        private byte[] _writeBuffer = new byte[4096];
        private byte[] _readBuffer = new byte[262144];

        public bool IsConnected => _connectionWaitHandle.WaitTask().IsCompleted;

        public event EventHandler Connected;
        public event EventHandler Closed;
        public event EventHandler<ValueTuple<string, DateTime>> MessageReceived;

        public ResilientWebSocket(string url) => _url = new Uri(url);

        public async ValueTask Initialise()
        {
            if (_disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ResilientWebSocket", "Object has been disposed");
            await Reconnect().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task Send(string message)
        {
            if (Log.IsEnabled(LogEventLevel.Verbose))
            {
                Log.Verbose($"Sending message: {message}");
            }

            var errorCounter = 0;

            do
            {
                if (_disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ResilientWebSocket", "Object has been disposed");

                try
                {
                    int length;

                    unsafe
                    {
                        fixed (char* pMessage = message)
                        fixed (byte* pBuffer = _writeBuffer)
                        {
                            // Will throw if buffer is too small
                            length = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(pMessage, message.Length, pBuffer, _writeBuffer.Length);
                        }
                    }

                    if (errorCounter > 0)
                    {
                        Log.Debug($"About to send length: {length} Message: {message}");
                    }

                    var sendTask = _webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(_writeBuffer, 0, length), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true,
                        CancellationToken.None);

                    if (errorCounter > 0)
                    {
                        Log.Debug($"Send task: {sendTask}. About to await with timeout");
                    }

                    await sendTask.TimeoutAfter(SendTimeoutMs).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (errorCounter > 0)
                    {
                        Log.Debug($"Awaited Send successfully");
                    }

                    break;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ae) when (ae.ParamName == "bytes")
                {
                    Log.Warning($"Write buffer size ({_writeBuffer.Length}) too small for message. Doubling..");
                    _writeBuffer = new byte[_writeBuffer.Length * 2];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error(e, $"Error writing message {message} to web socket");

                    if (_webSocket == null)
                    {
                        Log.Debug("Websocket was null. Initiating reconnection");
                        await Reconnect().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    if (errorCounter++ >= 10)
                    {
                        Log.Debug($"Error counter has reached 10. Reconnecting..");
                        await Reconnect().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(200).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

            } while (true);
        }

        public Task Reset()
        {
            if (_disposed) return Task.CompletedTask;

            if (!IsConnected)
            {
                Log.Debug("Reset() called when web socket is not connected. Ignoring.");
                return _connectionWaitHandle.WaitTask();
            }

            Log.Information("Resetting websocket connection");
            return Reconnect();
        }

        public Task ConnectionReadyAsync() => _connectionWaitHandle.WaitTask();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                _disposed = true;

                Log.Debug("Disposing web socket");
                EnsureClosed().Wait();
            }
        }

        private async Task Reconnect()
        {
            if (_disposed) return;

            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _reconnecting, 1, 0) == 0)
            {
                Log.Debug($"Initiating web socket reconnection to {_url}");

                try
                {
                    _connectionWaitHandle.Reset();

                    while (!IsConnected)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await EnsureClosed().ConfigureAwait(false);

                            _webSocket = new ClientWebSocket
                            {
                                Options = {KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)}
                            };

                            Log.Information($"Opening connection to {_url}");

                            await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_url, CancellationToken.None).TimeoutAfter(OpenTimeoutMs).ConfigureAwait(false);

                            Log.Debug("Web socket opened");
                            _connectionWaitHandle.Set();

                            _ = Task.Run(() => ReceiveLoop(_webSocket));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.Error(e, $"Error reconnecting to {_url}");
                        }

                        if (!IsConnected)
                        {
                            Log.Information("Connection unsuccessful. Sleeping for 5 seconds before retrying..");
                            await Task.Delay(RetryOpenDelayMs).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _reconnecting = 0;
                }

                try
                {
                    Connected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex, "Error in connection opened event handler");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Debug("Reconnection already in progress. Ignoring Reconnect request");
            }
        }

        private async void ReceiveLoop(WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            try
            {
                var offset = 0;

                while (webSocket != null && webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Closed && webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Aborted && !_disposed)
                {
                    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(_readBuffer, offset, _readBuffer.Length - offset),
                        CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        await EnsureClosed().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else if (result.CloseStatus == null)
                    {
                        if (result.EndOfMessage)
                        {
                            var message = Encoding.Default.GetString(_readBuffer, 0, offset + result.Count);

                            if (Log.IsEnabled(LogEventLevel.Verbose))
                            {
                                Log.Verbose($"Message received: {message}");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, (message, dateTime));
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.Error(e, "Error in message received event handler");
                            }

                            offset = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            offset += result.Count;

                            if (offset >= _readBuffer.Length - 1)
                            {
                                Log.Warning($"Read buffer size ({_readBuffer.Length}) too small for message. Doubling..");
                                var newReadBuffer = new byte[_readBuffer.Length * 2];
                                Array.Copy(_readBuffer, newReadBuffer, offset);

                                _readBuffer = newReadBuffer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.Debug($"Web socket closed. Status: {result.CloseStatus} Reason: {result.CloseStatusDescription}");

                        Closed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Web socket error during receive");
            }

            await Reconnect().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private async Task EnsureClosed()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_webSocket != null && _webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Aborted && _webSocket.State != WebSocketState.CloseReceived && _webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Closed)
                {
                    Log.Debug($"Closing web socket in state {_webSocket.State}");
                    await _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None).TimeoutAfter(CloseTimeoutMs);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Error closing web socket");
            }

            _webSocket = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You lost me at `My overview` header and content. How does this relate to what you have above it? How does this not functional code snippet relate to `TimeoutAfter` that precedes it?

Comment: @Igor, I want to call `TimeoutAfter` outside this class. For example, if this web socket wrapper class is named `ResilientWebSocket`. I want to have something like: `var client = new ResilientWebSocket(); client.DoTimeout => () = TimeoutAfter(5000)`. Did you get the idea? The timeout functionality should taken out of this class, so it's customizable by whoever instantiates the ResilientWebSocket class.

Comment: You need to update your question with more clarification and examples of what you mean.

Comment: That person would probably (hopefully) not reinvent the wheel and use something like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) instead. It's unlikely that whatever you offer as a wrapper is more flexible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you are saying that I can do the same as the `Func<T>` example (taking functionality outside the class for customizability) with Polly? I mean if it handles all calls correctly, I will definitely use it. By correctly I mean look at the webSocket.ConnectAsync, webSocket.SendAsync, etc., they don't use a CancellationToken in the wrapper I gave.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I added the code from the entire web socket wrapper. I'm interested in Polly, but I'm not sure if it's suitable in this case, because the calls are not using a CancellationToken and as much as I know, it relies on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your use case, but I'll give it a shot. Perhaps you can try the Template design pattern here, as it looks to me that you only want to customize the time-out behavior and not the call/execution order. Though I may not be understanding the problem correctly.

Using delegates or Func types can also work, but in my experience it often confuses developers down the line, especially if the logic gets more complicated.

Comment: The template design pattern makes `abstract` stuff and you create a method where you execute them in order. That's not even close to what I need. What I need is every single `_webSocket.XXX` call should have an appropriate timeout. You know you can use a simple CancellationToken with `CancelAfter` or the solution I provided. I liked the idea for Polly, just like the guy in the comments mentioned.